# Что делает оператор =>

Tags: c#

В документации написано, что опертор => не может быть перегружен, однако кроме объявления лямбда выражений, я видел подобное использование:  `static int a => 5;` И теперь к а можно обращаться как к константе этого класса. Почему оно так работает?

Comment: Читайте документацию https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator#expression-body-definition

Comment: это сокращённый вид записи функций и синтаксис для записи лямбда функций

Comment: @iKuzmichov Но почему когда я хочу получить значение от этой лямбды, мне не нужно ее вызывать скобками?

Comment: И снова читать документацию https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties
неужели так сложно перейти по ссылкам?…

Comment: @AlexeyTen Теперь понял, большое спасибо

Comment: @AlexeyTen, надо было оформить ответом.

Comment: Мне совесть не позволяет. Я на c# ни одной строчки не написал, а эти две ссылки просто нагуглил =0

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) явно указано, что токен `=>` может встречаться в двух случаях:

1. lambda operator: в этом случае он разделяет входные параметры, указываемые слева от него, от тела лямбды, расположенного справа.
2. Expression body definition: в этом случае слева указывается описание члена класса, справа - тело выражения.
   Синтаксис в общем виде выглядит так:

   ```
   member => expression;
   ```

   пример с методом `ToString`, запись

   ```
   public override string ToString() => $"{fname} {lname}".Trim();
   ```

   равносильна следующей

   ```
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return $"{fname} {lname}".Trim();
   }
   ```

   В вопросе запись `static int a => 5;` равносильна `readonly property`

   ```
   static int a { get; } = 5
   ```